# Assistance Needed in Retrieving Azure App Service Information Using Azure Python SDK

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I am currently in the process of verifying and ensuring that the existing App Services are utilizing the following configuration:

*Stack: PHP*

*Major version: PHP 8*

*Minor version: PHP 8.2*

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMC27.png)

To accomplish this, I need to retrieve the **"General Setting"** information of the App Service for inspection. I am using the Azure Python SDK, specifically the "azure-mgmt-web" package, to make API calls. I have attempted to retrieve a List of App Services by Resource Group, but it does not include the required information. Consequently, I have not yet identified a suitable API resource to obtain these details.

Could you please assist me in finding documentation or guides that would enable me to retrieve the mentioned information? I've provided an example for PHP, and additionally, I need to check App Services utilizing Python and Java.

Package link: [azure-mgmt-web](https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-web/)

Microsoft documentation link: [Azure Python SDK Web Apps Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-web/azure.mgmt.web.v2023_01_01.operations.webappsoperations?view=azure-python#azure-mgmt-web-v2023-01-01-operations-webappsoperations-list-by-resource-group)

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You can call this Rest API via your python sdk -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/provider/get-available-stacks?view=rest-appservice-2022-03-01 to get the Web app runtime

Comment: @SiddheshDesai 
I have also tried this API, but it only returns a list of runtime environments. It doesn't contain any information related to App Services :(

Comment: I tried using this **[API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/get?view=rest-appservice-2022-03-01)** and received entire details of the Web App:-

![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/KmjnimQ.png)

Comment: Refer here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/get?view=rest-appservice-2022-03-01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below code to retrieve the details of my PHP web app via Python SDK and I was able to print the **`Runtime Version`** of my Web app and its details including **`site_config`**.

**My Code:-**

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.web import WebSiteManagementClient

subscription_id = 'xxxxxxx7cb2a7'
resource_group_name = 'siliconrg798'
site_name = 'PHPsiliconWebapp'
tenant_id = 'xxxxxx38592395'

# Initialize the credential object with specific tenant ID
credential = DefaultAzureCredential(authority="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant_id)

# Initialize the WebSiteManagementClient with the credential object
web_client = WebSiteManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

# Call the API to get information about the specified web app
web_app = web_client.web_apps.get(resource_group_name, site_name)
# Accessing the runtime stack
runtime_stack = web_app.site_config.linux_fx_version  # Replace with the appropriate property name for Windows stack

# Accessing other properties
client_affinity_enabled = web_app.client_affinity_enabled
https_only = web_app.https_only
# Access more properties similarly based on the response object's structure


print("Runtime Stack:", runtime_stack) #print Runtime stack
print("Client Affinity Enabled:", client_affinity_enabled) #print Affinity
print("HTTPS Only:", https_only) #print Https enabled property

# Print the response or access its properties
print(web_app.site_config) #print all the website configuration properties
print(web_app) #print entire web app properties
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

Alternatively you can make use this [**REST API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/get-configuration?view=rest-appservice-2022-03-01&tryIt=true&source=docs#) to get Web App properties:-

***Rest API:-***

```http
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionid/resourceGroups/resourcegroupname/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/name?api-version=2022-03-01
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer, I tried it and it seems there is no other way to get the exact "Major Version and Minor Version" other than the way you are instructing.

Comment: Yes, There's no other way with SDK's. But you can definetely get those with Azure CLI and Azure Powershell commands, If you want I can share those with you

Comment: Thank you for your dedicated help. But I can only use the SDK to get the necessary information. I will look for more, once again, thank you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/get-key-rotation-policy/get-key-rotation-policy?view=rest-keyvault-keys-7.4&tabs=HTTP Here's the Rest API for the same

Comment: Do not post a question as an answer, You need to create a new question or ask the doubt via comments here

Comment: Refer this Github document to configure and get the rotation keys in key vault via python sdk- https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-keys#configure-automatic-key-rotation